# SQlite: Create New column

Tags: sqlite

I have a table like this. I am trying to **auto-fill** the expiry column if **empty**.

```
Name       Registered   Expiry
A          2017-08-13   null
B          2014-04-21   2014-09-15
C          2018-06-15   2019-8-15
```

How would I do?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(Expiry) Values( Registered+30 days) Where Expiry IS NULL
```

Comment: Easy to do with `date()`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and using UPDATE, not INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `update` and not `insert` a new record

```
update your_table
set expiry = date(Registered , '30 days')
where expiry is null
```